# What is the correct way to check firebase db ref on client side(i.e. in javascript)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While using `firebaseDB.ref("some-node-ref-that-does-not-exist/")` how can I make a null check. This line of code still getting invoked with even above node does not exists in my firebase db.

Comment: What exactly needs to be checked for null?  Are you getting an error message?  What isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: I have two backend environment one of them is configured with firebase. There is single client side application where I have used firebase sdk. Now if client application point to the second backend point where firebase is not configured, it stops making calls to firebase db. So I want to know if firebase db does not exists, It should make regular polling.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if there is data at a specific node in the Realtime Database, you **have to** query this node and look if the [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html) exists.

With the JavaScript SDK you would do as follows, using the [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#exists) method:

```
ref.once('value')
  .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {....}
  });
```